# Query an array of objects and return the target

Tags: javascript

I need to find an object in an array by a key and value

I'm trying to do a search on an array of objects with for in. but I can not.

My input:

```
findObject[{ a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }, { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }, { c: 3 }] //the last argument ({ c: 3 }) is the target
```

What I'm trying to return:

```js
{ a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }
```

Note: The array of objects can have any object and the target too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the item in the array whose values contain an object whose `c` property is `3`:

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }, { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }, { c: 3 }]
const result = arr.find(e => Object.values(e).some(k => k.c == 3))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I couldn't use it like that. The target can have any key or value, and so can the array of objects.

Comment: @unr my solution will work for any key. What would you like the solution to do better?

Comment: I repeat. the target can be any object, like `{ asundoaisudn: 1203870, s: Object, a: { b: { c: { as: { sai: 10 } } } } }``` can be any random key and value. and the objects inside the array too. so find would not find it if the key was different from c === 3

Answer (score 1):

What the OP is looking for is a find using deep equality (keys and values, including nested keys and values are equal). Even shallow equality [is a deep topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) in JS and applying it recursively is even deeper.

A fast but flawed idea is comparing JSON encodings for the two objects being compared. I wave a hand at that in the snippet, but prefer to use a utility that has thought through edge cases and probably executes fast.

```js
function isEqual(a, b) {
  // not good, but quick to code:
  // return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
  
  // lodash has put some thought into it
  return _.isEqual(a, b)
}

// find the first object in  array with a value deeply equal to object
function findObject(array, object) {
  return array.find(el => {
    return Object.values(el).some(v => isEqual(v, object))
  })
}


let array = [{ a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }, { a: 1, b: { c: 3, d: { e: "hi" }} }];
let object = { c: 3, d: { e: "hi" }};

let result = findObject(array, object);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The OP asks to find the last object of an array as the target in the array up to that point.  Adopt as follows...

```
// array is the array to search plus the last item is the thing to search for
let firstObjects = array.slice(0, -1)
let lastObject = array.at(-1)
let result = findObject(firstObjects, lastObject)
```